# How do I return the shortest snippet from a keyword search?

Tags: javascript

I have the following task to solve:

> Given a page of content with alphanumeric words, and a search phrase
>   of N words, write an algorithm that will return the shortest snippet
>   of content that contains all N words in any order.

This is what I have so far. I got the text on the page into an array without punctuation:

```
var allText = $('#all-text').text();
var punctuationless = allText.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/g," ").toLowerCase();
var lessSpaces = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
var allTextArray = lessSpaces.split(" ");
var keywords = [];
```

I think I can probably use the .filter method, but I'm not sure how to compare two arrays.

```
allTextArray.filter(keywords)
//find the indexes of the matches to the keywords
//compare how far apart the indexes are to each other and return the shortest length
```

Comment: Not certain interpret _"write an algorithm that will return the shortest snippet of content that contains all N words"_ correctly ? What is "shortest snippet of content" ?

Comment: Example: The George Washington Bridge in New York City is one of the oldest bridges ever constructed. It is now being remodeled because the bridge is a landmark. City officials say that the landmark bridge effort will create a lot of new jobs in the city.

Search Terms: Landmark City Bridge

Result: bridge is a landmark. City

Comment: _"Search Terms: Landmark City Bridge Result: bridge is a landmark. City"_ Why would "is a" be included in results ?

Comment: I have to return the snippet (part of the sentence or paragraph that the keywords fall in), not just the words.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @Katrin, Could you provide a few more examples?

Comment: This is confusing. Concrete examples in the original question would have ensured more answers.

Answer (score 4):

So, to list some examples as I understand the OP, if the page text were:

```
One for the money,
two for the show.
```

- The search terms `"One", "money"` should produce `"One for the money"`.
- The search terms `"One","two","for"` should produce `"One for the money, two"`
- The search terms `"for","show"` should produce `"for the show"`

  - ... but **NOT** `for the money, two for the show`

I add that last point because that's where such a function gains a lot of complexity, since it now has to find the combination of search terms that is smallest in size out of all combinations.

I worked out **[a jsfiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadDeveloper/cz9fpx2y/3/)** to this, but I won't claim that it's the most efficient possible answer (since it's late, and parts of my mind may have gone to bed).

Basically, its an iterate and scan ahead solution, which is probably how a person would do it with their eyeballs:

1. Makes a pass of the search text and builds an array of each occurrence of every keyword and its index.
2. Makes sure the order of the array is based on the order the keywords occur in the text.
3. Starts at (almost) each entry in the ordered array and scans to the right until it finds at least one occurrence of each keyword -- at which point we see if it's the smallest snippet we've gotten so far.

After all is said and done, all possible snippets included all keywords are check.

It's **important to note** that the solution I created is not case sensitive and it matches parts of words, not whole words only, and the OP implies case insensitivity and whole word matching.

The strategies for case insensitivity (converting all input text to lowercase) and full word matching (stripping text of punctuation and extra white space, then split into an array) should be readily applicable to the solution, especially since `indexOf` works the same for strings and arrays.

```
getSnippet = function(keywords, fullText) {
  var keywordCount = keywords.length,
      keywordIndexes = [];

  // Find each occurrence of every word
  for(var i=0; i < keywordCount; i++) {
    var searchPos = 0;
    var word = keywords[i];
    var index = -1;
    do {
      index = fullText.indexOf(keywords[i],searchPos);
      if (index >= 0) {
        keywordIndexes.push({i:index, word:word});
      }
      searchPos = index + 1;
    } while (index >= 0);
  }

  keywordIndexes.sort(function(a, b) { return a.i == b.i ? 0 : a.i < b.i ? -1 : 1; });

  // Find the shortest run by starting at each array index and scanning to the
  // right until we have encountered each word in the list.
  for (i=0, n=keywordIndexes.length-keywordCount; i<=n; i++) {
    // NOTE: We actually can actually stop once there are fewer keyword
    // indexes than keywords, since we know we won't find all the keywords (hence the subtraction of keywordCount)
    var foundWords = {},
        foundCount = 0;
    snippetStart = keywordIndexes[i].i;

    for (j=i; j < keywordIndexes.length; j++) {
      var word = keywordIndexes[j].word;
      if (!foundWords[word]) {
        foundWords[word] = true;
        foundCount++;
      }
      if (foundCount == keywordCount) {
        // We've found all the words
        snippetEnd = keywordIndexes[j].i + word.length;
        if (minSnippet.end - minSnippet.start > snippetEnd - snippetStart) {
          minSnippet.end = snippetEnd;
          minSnippet.start = snippetStart;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return fullText.substring(minSnippet.start, minSnippet.end);
}
```

See the **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadDeveloper/cz9fpx2y/3/)** for more info.

Comment: Theoretically, you could make one pass of the text and look for ALL keywords, rather than looking through the text once for EACH keyword.  This can eliminate the need to sort the keywords, making the solution more efficient.  But the code would be harder to understand and the efficiency gain wouldn't be noticeable in most real-world cases, so I've left the solution as-is.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses two arrays, `q` array for a sorted list of wanted words and their position:

```
[
    {
        "word": "bridge",
        "pos": 46
    },
    {
        "word": "city",
        "pos": 65
    },
    {
        "word": "bridge",
        "pos": 155
    },
    ...
]
```

and `qq` array for groups of all possible words in direct neighbourhood. It includes the start and end of the wanted parts. This list is basically sorted to get the smallest length and is taken for the result.

```
[
    {
        "start": 155,
        "end": 181
    },
    {
        "start": 177,
        "end": 220
    },
    ...
]
```

The algorithm looks for complete words in the original text, only with `toLowerCase` applied.

```js
function getWords() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').textContent,
        lowerText = text.toLowerCase(),
        wordsO = {},
        words = document.getElementById('words').value.split(' ').map(function (w) { wordsO[w.toLowerCase()] = true; return w.toLowerCase(); }),
        pattern = /\w+/g,
        execResult,
        result = [],
        q = [], qq = [], i, max;

    while ((execResult = pattern.exec(lowerText)) !== null) {
        wordsO[execResult[0]] && q.push({ word: execResult[0], pos: execResult.index });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < q.length - words.length + 1; i++) {
        max = words.reduce(function (r, w) {
            var j = i;
            while (j < q.length && q[j].word !== w) {
                j++;
            }
            return !~r || j === q.length ? -1 : j > r ? j : r;
        }, i);
        ~max && qq.push({ start: q[i].pos, end: q[max].pos + q[max].word.length });
    }

    qq.sort(function (a, b) { return a.end - a.start - b.end + b.start; });

    qq.every(function (a, _, aa) {
        return aa[0].end - aa[0].start === a.end - a.start && result.push(text.substring(a.start, a.end) + ' [' + a.start + ']');
    });

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.length && '<ul>' + result.map(function (a) { return '<li>' + a + '</li>'; }).join('') + '</ul>' || '### no match found ###';
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="65" id="text">001 002 003 004 001 002 The George Washington Bridge in New York City is one of the oldest bridges ever constructed. It is now being remodeled because the bridge is a landmark. City officials say that the landmark bridge effort will create a lot of new jobs in the city.</textarea><br />
    <input type="text" id="words" value="Landmark City Bridge" /> <button onclick="getWords()">search</button>
</form>
Found search: <br />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This only seems to get the last instance of the search term, what if there are multiple instances